# Traversing through a array of lists

Tags: c#, arrays, traversal

Suppose I have a **array** of **lists**

myArr

Suppose i want to traverse through the FIRST list (which would be element 0 in my array) and then STOP. Is that possible?

right now I am using

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArr[0].count; i++)
{
  do stuff
  IF the array has gone to the next element  in the ARRAY (Not the first    LIST) Then break out of for loop
}
```

but it is traversing through the WHOLE array (thus 7 lists)! I want it to just traverse through the FIRST list in my array. Any ideas?

For example if I have

```
[0][0] = "cat"
[0][1] = "dog"
[1][0] = "seal"
```

I only want iterate through until i get cat and dog (or until the first lists has been traversed through) I don't care about seal and the rest of the lists contained in the elements of my array for this particular case

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < myjagArray[0].count; i++)` does not really specify traverse through what. it just counts. you must specify it with your algorithm inside loop.

Comment: What are you doing inside the for loop? `myArr[0][i]` should access the items in the first nested array.

Comment: It's irrelevant what I'm doing in the for loop though right? I only want to loop until I get to the 2nd element (i.e. 1)

Comment: @Shammy No, it isn't

Comment: Well, I fail to see how ```for(int i = 0; i < myArr[0].Count(); i++)``` doesn't work. You'd want to have a body that does: ```myArr[0][i] or myArr[0].at(i)```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually not problematic. This should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < myArr[0].Count; i++) Console.WriteLine(myArr[0][i]);
```

Comment: You are correct, I'll flag this for moderators to delete immediately. Apparently I had a for loop that my code was inside of, so it looked like it was still iterating through, but it actually wasn't, the code out side of it made it just execute the code again. So my code was working all along lol.

Comment: @Shammy well ok, glad you got it going :) just one note though: note that everyone made a comment about how the rest of the code wasn't irrelevant -- try to understand what they (we) meant

Comment: Understood completely.

Comment: @Shammy You can delete your own question, you do not need a moderator for that.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't let me. Guess it's because it has answers.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose i want to traverse through the FIRST list (which would be element 0 in my array) and then STOP. Is that possible?

Yes.

Your example is not really useful.  You can stop a `for` statement using the `break` statement pretty much anywhere...

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if (i = 5) // any condition really...
  {
    break;
  }
}
```

for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if (i = 5)
  {
    break;
  }
  Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Outputs:

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4

Comment: EXACTLY!!! This is what I'm looking for but HOW do you do that with my particular case? I want to stop when I get to the second element in my array but looping until i get to fieldinfoarray[1].count doesn't work, it iterates through the  whole array

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear enough for me to understand in what case you want to use the `break` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to do this

```
using System.Linq;
```

...

```
var firstList = myArr.Take(1);
foreach(var item in firstList)
{
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have an array of lists created as follows:

```
List<string>[] myArr = new List<string>[2];
myArr[0] = new List<string>(new string[] { "cat", "dog" });
myArr[1] = new List<string>(new string[] { "seal" });
```

Then we can traverse through (and print) the first array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArr[0].Count; i++)
    System.Console.WriteLine(myArr[0][i]);
```